# Extra strange characters when pasting from clipman clipboard manager

Tags: clipboard, x-windows

I want to paste a clipboard entry, say 12345, from the graphical clipboard manager `clipman` to a terminal emulator. It is set up to combine the selection and the clipboard. I called up the clipboard history window, select the entry via the mouse and paste it in the terminal using the middle-button.

This is what appears:

```
^[[200~12345~
```

I know this can happen via a keyboard paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> erroneusly. I don't understand why this happen and how to avoid it with a middle-button paste.

This happens also with the `clipit` clipboard manager. I'm using a XFCE-4 desktop environment.